# Merging old deleted orphaned file in Subversion into new version of the same file

Tags: svn, merge

I have the following history in SVN; I'm going to rename + renumber for simplicity.

- r10000 `path/to/foo.c`
- r10001 `path/to/bar.c` was added by a coworker, where bar.c is a copy of foo.c, with minor changes. But `svn copy` was not used and so that historical link was lost

At this point I started to fix things:

- r10002 `path/to/bar.c` removed
- r10003 `path/to/bar.c` copied from `path/to/foo.c`

Now I would like to merge `path/to/bar.c` in r10001 into `path/to/bar.c` in r10003.

How can I do this? I've tried the following (in the `/path/to` working copy):

```
> svn merge bar.c@10001 bar.c
svn: E195002: Invalid merge source 'bar.c'; a working copy path can only be used with a repository revision (a number, a date, or head)

> svn merge https://server/path/to/bar.c@10001 bar.c
svn: E195016: 'https://server/path/to/bar.c@10001' must be ancestrally related to 'https://server/path/to/bar.c@10003'

> svn merge --ignore-ancestry https://server/path/to/bar.c@10001 bar.c
svn: E200004: Cannot merge automatically while ignoring mergeinfo
```

I'm stuck. If I do `svn cat bar.c@10001 >bar.c` and then commit changes, would this capture history acceptably? At least it would get `bar.c`'s to the correct content.